# Jamaica visit for business

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens

I am traveling to Jamaica via a US port. Since Jamaica has on arrival visa for Indian citizens, do I need a transit visa for the USA? My next flight from the USA is 4 hours later.

Answer (score 1):

You are an Indian national travelling to Jamaica. You are making a transfer in the USA. To transit in the US, you need a C-1 visa.

> If you are a non-US citizen and are merely passing through the United
>   States while transiting to another foreign country, a C-1 transit visa
>   is an appropriate non-immigrant visa. If you are traveling with your
>   family, each person regardless of age, even children and babies listed
>   in parents' passports, needs to apply for a separate C-1 Visa. Persons
>   from the countries that qualify for the Visa Waiver program can
>   transit to the US without a transit visa.
>
> An immigration officer at the port of entry can admit a person holding
>   a C-1 transit visa for the duration determined by him/her, but for a
>   maximum duration of 29 days. You must leave the U.S. on the proposed
>   flight or ship of departure, or within 29 days, whichever is earlier.
>   You must pass in immediate and continuous transit through the U.S.
>
> A transit visa is particularly very useful if you need to change 
>   airports in the U.S. Even if you don't need to change the airport, if
>   there is a long delay before you can board your flight to the final
>   destination, instead of waiting in the airport, you can get out and
>   tour the nearby places, visit friends or family members, or do
>   shopping.
>
> However, even if you are planning to stay in the U.S. even for a day,
>   you should apply for the B1/B2 visa.

It seems strange that your only choice is a visa which allows you to leave the airport, but okay. I would advise that you avoid transferring in the US if you don't want to deal with the hassle of a visa application and an interview.

Info obtained from [here](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/transitvisa/c1visa.html).